# Is it possible to write .member and assume the class/struct in C#

Tags: c#

I want to do something like the below

```
using (MyClass)
{
.a = a;
.title = sz;
.abc = paramEFG
etc = .lol;
}
```

Is that possible in C#? obviously not with that syntax but perhaps another keyword?

Answer (score 3):

Well, not entirely in that way, as far as I know, although *object initializers* get close:

```
var foo = new MyClass
{
  a = a,
  title = sz,
  abc = paramEFG
};
```

But obviously, they only work for creating objects and initializing properties directly after calling the constructor, not at any point like VB's `With` (which has almost the exact syntax you're describing in your question).

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not present in the language. You are perhaps thinking of the *with* keyword of JavaScript or Visual Basic?

Answer (score 1):

C# does not support that.
VB does, using the `With` keyword.

If MyClassis a very long (eg, `this.Controls[0].Controls[3].Font`), you can assign a local variable with a shorter name to it.

If it's a long class name (eg, `Dictionary<RichTextBox, List<GroupPanel>>`), you can use the `using` statement to create an alias, like this:

```
using MyThingy = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox, System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Windows.Forms.GroupPanel>>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant do this in C#, its more of a VB thing. You could however design a fluid interface like so:

```
var c = MyClass.Build()
.SetA(a)
.SetTitle(sz);
.SetParam(paramEFG);
```

or you could use the C# 3 syntax and do

```
var c = new MyClass() {
  A = a, 
  Title = sz 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are asking for a feature like VB.Net's With operator.

```
With someClass
 .Name = "foo"
 .IntValue = 42
End With
```

If so, no this is not possible in C#.